# Is there a way to change the edge from 'Auto Smooth' mode to a complete curve?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, normals, bevel

## My purpose

I made the following modeling to make parts for the robot’s tilt arm.

---

## What I tried

I first used the `Surface subdivision` modifier to express softness and curves. However, using this modifier with the `Bevel` modifier does not produce the results I want. In more detail, after applying the `Surface sudivision` modifier, it is difficult to express the slope and sharpness of the edges, using `Bevel Weight` and `Crease`. Thus I found out that, for the slope and sharpness of the complexly constructed edges, there was a function called `Auto Smooth`, partly by looking for an easy way to apply softness.

With ‘Auto Smooth’ function, it was easy to apply soft effect while maintaining sharpness of each edges. And using the `Weighted Normal` modifier, it formed a more realistic surface (*I still don't understand the `Weight normal`*).

## Point

Most of them have been resolved, but unlike `Surface Subdivision`, `Auto Smooth` does not soften to the outlines.

[image]
[image]

*The outline is not smooth and still angular.*

---

## To get a clear answer

- I know that `Auto Smooth` function does not actually make the surface
  smooth, it only makes light rendering smooth. However, if I render
  later, if the outline fails to come out smoothly, I can't make a
  realistic rendering.
- Also, I think it difficult to maintain the model in the future to
  divide Surface from the beginning of the modeling.

---

Q. **Excluding the above concerns, is there a way to smooth the outline?**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do two things.

1. Add more *Bevel segments*, so the shading works properly
2. Add the *Subdivision Modifier* to "smooth the outline"

(There's no need for the *Weighted Normal* modifier.)

[image]

Note:
I'd also *strongly* reccomend, that you make your model *all quads*.
Most of your problems are caused by n-gons.

**Edit:**
To keep your corners sharp, add more geometry manually, without the *Subdivision modifier.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but what does "make your model all quads" mean?

Comment: @Mast It's a suggestion to only use faces with four sides when modeling. N-gons (faces with more sides) lead to shading issues and problems with subdivision :).

Comment: Ah! Good tip indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I hope the bevel and sharpness apply like the picture I uploaded. That's a good way, but even after I make it into a quad, Its can't maintain some sharpness and bevel.

Comment: Please check the updated post.

Comment: Oh, I think it was short. I'll try to do it that way. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ Thank you very much for your knowledge and hard work. ㅠㅁㅠ The easiest way, too, is to increase the geometry in the beginning. Is Surface subdivision not suitable?

Comment: @bakuiseok Yeah, I just rebuilt it from scratch. But I'm sure there are more ways to do it :). Good luck with your project.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ Thank you!